# How to embed executable jar file in webpage?

Tags: angularjs, jar, html, executable-jar

I'm pretty new to web development. Though I want to create a single page web application where I can allow users to run executable jar file created for doing some activity or else made it available for download.
I have got some results on internet, but it was for running applet in web browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution?